# button autoresize

Tags: iphone, icons, button, resolution, autoresize

Can anyone help me with the small buttons/icons used within the iphone apps. I am fairly new to the app world and trying to make some buttons(viz the tick box) for my app. I am not sure if we should start with a 50X50 and autoresize in the app or just have a 20X20 which exactly fits the space...

Any help on this is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple, buttons should be at least 44px wide, and 44px high (unless they're by themselves with nothing near them, in which case 22px high). If you're laying out buttons in IB, I'd say get them placed correctly, and set their 'springs and struts' to autosize for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this,

Put 50*50 button that you need in your project ,and add an image to your interface builder,
select the image that you put recently in Button attributes and select button size by ctrl+3

and set it to 20*20 it works ,it works for me also...